# Crontab Scheduling In Digital Ocean Server

Tags: node.js, server, cron, scheduled-tasks, digital-ocean

I have the following schedule in my local crontab file:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /Users/harrisoncramer/CrontabScripts/dsca-arms-sales/xmlParser.js
```

It uses node to run a local copy of my file. I have also stored this node project on Digital Ocean. However, when I attempt to write a very similar schedule, I get the following error:

```
"/tmp/crontab.Wf1279/crontab":0: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

The crontab file looks like this:

```
10/* * * * * nodejs /home/harrisoncramer/dsca_sales_tracker/xmlParser.js

# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task....etc.....
```

Digital Ocean specifies that when you'd like to use node to run an application, you should reference nodejs in your crontab. **The script works when I simply use all wildcard operators. It breaks when I try to convert this to "every 10 minutes."**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `*/10` is not the same as `10/*`.

Comment: Wow. So simple, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crontab syntax wrong is off. To run a command e.g. every 10 minutes use 
 
`*/10 * * * * /path/to/the/command`.

You can find more information about crontab configs [here](https://stuff.21zoo.com/content/posts/crontab-every-5-minutes/).